# Powershell Time Difference between ranges

Tags: powershell, time

This is more of a logistic issue than actual coding, however I am hoping there is some trick I don't know about that could help me.

I need to calculate the time between 2 date/time stamps, with a catch.
Example:

```
startDate = September 19, 2015 02:11:46 AM
endDate = October 16, 2015 08:25:27 AM
paused = [array of date/time stamps for when the ticket switches to paused]
unpaused = [array of date/time stamps for when the ticket unpauses]
```

So here is what I need, I need to know the elapsed time between the start and end dates, with the following exceptions:

- Time in paused should not count towards elapsed time
- Time before 7am should not count towards elapsed time
- Time after 5pm should not count towards elapsed time
- Time on weekends should not count towards elapsed time

My approach was simply to get the difference between start and end, then subtract the elapsed time from paused status.  Then to subtract time for evenings and weekends.  This didn't work because I ended up double dipping if it was paused on a weekend.

I am looking for a clever way to do this without having write a million if statements and step through each day in the life of this.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You could probably use [Time Period Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx?msg=3828883#xx3828883xx). It won't magically do all the work for you but it might help simplify the task.

Comment: That looks like it would help a TON,  is there a powershell version of it though?  I have to keep this as close to stock PS as possible.  I couldn't figure out how to actually use that.